# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier <Component Name>. import call expects one or two arguments

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue 2.

I am trying to use a component (VueSlickCarousel) from npm.

I have installed the component using npm.

In my website I have added:

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

I am also using the VUE CDN:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2"></script>
```

I have a script like this:

```html
<script>
  import VueSlickCarousel from 'vue-slick-carousel';
  var app = new Vue({
    components: { VueSlickCarousel },
    ...
  })
</script>
```

I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'VueSlickCarousel'. import call expects one or two arguments.
```

How can I import this component? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Here, you're mixing a CDN import (vue) and an NPM import (vue-slick-carousel). You should use one or the other, not a mix. Prefer NPM instead of a CDN if you have a build time like Webpack/Vite. Here is the CDN btw: https://github.com/gs-shop/vue-slick-carousel#cdn Otherwise, be sure that you want to use that package (no updates for 2 years already).

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I removed the import statement, added the CDN, and changed the component declaration to `components: { VueSlickCarousel : window['vue-slick-carousel'] }`

Comment: Are you sure you need `window` here? Can't you pass `'vue-slick-carousel'` directly?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work if I exclude `window`. I'm not 100% sure why.

Comment: When you import it to your browser via a CDN, the context is added towards the actual window of your browser. Most of the time, you don't need it but here, Vue apparently doesn't know the context in which you are currently in. Which seems logic, I just wanted to be sure of that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the import statement and replacing it with the CDN + adding the following fixed the issue.

```js
components: { 
  VueSlickCarousel : window['vue-slick-carousel']
}
```